# Retrieve File from User's Documents Directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, text

I can successfully read and write a text file within the user's Documents directory for my iOS app. However, I will need to view this text file *myself*, retrieving it from the user's iPad.

I looked into sending it via email, but all of the links pointed me to MFMailComposer rather than some automated way of sending email. I looked into FTP uploading, but Apple doesn't seem to want me to use password protected FTP in my app. How can I go about making a text file in the user's Documents directory accessible from my own computer? I feel as if there must be some easier options for this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's iTunes File Sharing. It is probably the most "direct" way to do it, as it doesn't require any 3rd party service and frameworks. Read more about it at [Ray Wenderlich's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/itunes-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app) - the tutorial is a bit dated, but should still be valid for the most part.

For over the air sharing, I'd recommend [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). It is easy to use within your app and many of your future users will have an account already.

Lastly, if you require the functionality for your development purposes, you might want to take a look at [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) (formerly iPhone Explorer). It will allow you direct access to your apps documents folder and doesn't require you to alter your app in any way to work.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into these options. But, to be clear, I don't want to require action from the user (the text file I'm trying to read is updated every time they play the app). Do all of these options require some action from the user?

Comment: Provided that your textfile is being written into the documents folder autmatically by your app whenever necessary, no user action within the app is requires for the first and the last option. I wouldn't require users to use a third party tool to make use of your app though - itunes file sharing is fine. The second option requires a bit more effort on your part, since you would need to sync the file with dropbox when it gets changed, users need to be able to connect to db etc. Once set up however, it would save the file to the users dropbox without even requiring the device to be plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your App-Info.plist and add a row under Information Property List.
2. Name that row Application supports iTunes file sharing. You should see it auto completing.
3. Set the value to YES

That's all you need to do. Now you can access the files from your iTunes.

As of August 4, 2014, open up iTunes. In the top right corner, click on your device, but NOT the eject button. It might say iPhone. Click on the Apps tab and scroll to the bottom to File Sharing. Click on the desired app and the documents will appear.